# Permissions for a AWS Lambda function to list users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I have an AWS Lambda function that needs to be able to run this code:

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  .... other useful code ....
});
```

In other words it should be able to *listUsers*.

When setting the role in IAM for that, what kind of policy do I need?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to list the users in your Cognito User Pool, you need to allow `cognito-idp:ListUsers`. You can restrict this action to a specific user pool like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:<region>:<account>:userpool/<userpoolid>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Have a look at [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazoncognitouserpools.html).

Comment: I have tried but, I keep getting this error: Missing credentials in config .... No credentials to load ...
in my Xcode debugging console when running the iOS app. There must be some issue that I am not aware of.

Comment: This should not happen when running your code inside the Lambda environment. Can you try running your code in the AWS console?

Comment: I have first seen the message in Xcode, but did some test in the Lambda environment. And it seems to be the same. I reformulated the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472969/aws-lambda-functions-issue

Comment: I am a total AWS-Lambda beginner so I may be missing some basic elements.

Comment: Try requiring `aws-sdk` only with `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');`

Comment: You mean instead of "require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');" ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give the IAM role `cognito-identity:ListIdentities` for more information you can go.  https://iam.cloudonaut.io/reference/cognito-identity.html

There may be dependencies with that list operation.

You can also do
`cognito-identity:*` if you need a less restrictive policy for testing wise.

Comment: This is incorrect, the question is for _Amazon Cognito Your User Pools_ (`cognito-idp`) not _Amazon Cognito Federated Identities_ (`cognito-identity`).