# AWS Lambda functions issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have recently started trying to use AWS Lambda functions. Here is what I get in the *Execution results* window of the Lambda console, when clicking the *Test* button.

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Missing credentials in config\",
  \"code\":\"CredentialsError\",\"time\":\"2019-06-06T07:11:53.538Z\",
  \"originalError\":{\"message\":\"No credentials to load\",
  \"code\":\"CredentialsError\",\"time\":\"2019-06-06T07:11:53.538Z\"}}"
}
```

And here is the Lambda function source code:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');

AWS.config.update({
    region:'ap-northeast-1'
});

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
    var params = {
        UserPoolId: 'ap-northeast-1MY-POOL-ID',
        AttributesToGet: [
            'email'
        ],
        Limit: '2',
    };

    var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    try {
      const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params).promise()
      const response = {
        inBound: event.sub,
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }
      return response;
    } catch (err) {
        const response = {
            inBound: event.sub,
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
        return response;
    }
};
```

Since I have set up the roles and policy, I am not sure what kind of credentials and which config the error message is referring to.

Comment: Inside Lambda try requiring `aws-sdk` only with `var AWS = require('aws-sdk');`

Comment: Also no need to call `AWS.config.update`, the region is auto determined inside Lambda

Comment: Well, before I did that I had another error message and thought it was useful.
Anyway, I will try and see.

Comment: Does your Lambda and Cognito both are in the same region?

Comment: @jogold. I tried replacing with: require('aws-sdk') as you suggested and it works.
Beside you were right that I do not need AWS.config.update after that. If that was an answer I would accept (if that matters for you).

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana. Yes they are in the same region.

Answer (score 1):

First, replace the existing import statement with follows.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Second, allow the cognito user list permission to lambda role as follow.

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "cognito-idp:ListUsers"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:cognito-idp:ap-northeast-1:AWS_ACCOUNT_NO:userpool:*"
    ]
}
```

**Note**: Replace AWS_ACCOUNT_NO with your actual aws account number.